# Copy snowflake data from one environment to another (prod to dev)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am trying to automate cloning snowflake objects and data from production to dev using Jenkins for performing a load test for API which uses these snowflake objects for sourcing data.

This activity is only anticipated when ever the jenkins pipeline triggers and the newly created snowflake objects need to be deleted once after the tests completes.

Am just trying to understand What is the best way to copy a table/schema from one snowflake environment to another?

Have identified some methods going through snowflake documentations, but not sure that is the best way to go for.

Below are the steps identified and will be wrapped in a python script from Jenkins :-

Create external stage in prod using

```
create or replace stage AIR_TICKET_FACT_DSP url='s3://public-assets-lab/LoadTest/' CREDENTIALS=(aws_key_id=' A******'aws_secret_key=' **********') file_format = csv;
```

Copy table data to stage

```
COPY INTO @AIR_TICKET_FACT_DSP FROM EASEL_PDL.TICKET_FACT where cast(ISSUE_DATE as date)='2019-01-01'
```

From the Dev environment
Use the command to insert the data to dev table

```
COPY INTO dev.AIR_TICKET_FACT_DSP FROM @AIR_TICKET_FACT_DSP
```

Is this possible? If yes. is this the right approach?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By environments I assume you mean different Snowflake accounts? If so, have you considered data sharing or replication?

Comment: @NickW Thanks for the reply !
 I have considered data sharing and replication, but that will not work because I need the data to be inserted from prod to dev as part of a jenkins pipeline for a load testing and then delete it after the test.

Comment: You probably need to update your question with a full set of requirements/restrictions (such as the fact it will be part of a Jenkins pipeline) so that people can provide answers that meet your requirements

Comment: I would still use data sharing with CTAS statements from the share over COPY INTO statements.  There is no reason to push data out of Snowflake and then back in again when you can do it all natively inside of Snowflake.

Comment: @NickW Agreed. I have added more context in the question. Thanks for the suggestion.